# To find if the group of elements is a substring of another string in R or SAS ?

Tags: r, string, group-by, sas, dplyr

I want to find if the given elements under a group are the part of another string or no ? If they are then I want the group number of the string where it was the part. They should be **part** of another string.For example, 'Benefits, verify' is one string under group 1 and that is part of group 2 string (claims,verify,benefits,verify). I also want to count how many times it appears in another string.

For example

```
Column1                            group
Benefits,verify                      1
claims,verify,benefits,verify        2
inquiry,type                         3
claims,verify                        4
```

Output expected:

```
column1                        Part of group      count
Benefits, verify                 2                  1
claims,verify                    2                  1
inquiry,type                     -                  -
claims,verify,benefits,verify    -                  -
```

Comment: is not `claims verify` part of group 2 also?

Comment: claims,verify of group 4 is the part of group 2 only

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lavenshtein's distance`:

```
a = which(!`diag<-`(adist(dat$Column1,partial=T,ignore.case = T),NA),T)
merge(dat,aggregate(count~.,data.frame(a,count=1),sum),by.x="group",by.y="row",all=T)
  group                       Column1 col count
1     1               Benefits,verify   2     1
2     2 claims,verify,benefits,verify  NA    NA
3     3                  inquiry,type  NA    NA
4     4                 claims,verify   2     1
```